# NVIDIA not working on 19.10

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, intel-graphics, nvidia-optimus

I have NVIDIA mx 230 and intel and i cannot use NVIDIA.
Now few problems:

1) `$ nvidia-smi` gives the output

```
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

2)

```
$ prime-select query
nvidia
```

3) In settings, the active GPU is intel and in prime-select menu, it is NVIDIA.
4)

```
lspci | grep -i nvidia
02:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP108M [GeForce MX230] (rev a1)
```

5)

```
$ lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (Whiskey Lake)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] UHD Graphics 620 (Whiskey Lake)
    Kernel modules: i915
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP Thermal Controller (rev 30)
--
02:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP108M [GeForce MX230] (rev ff)
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
```

Also, in additional driver, there is driver selected for nvidia. I have searched all forums and yet couldnt find a solution. i have tried to swith and reboot multiple times both via prime-select command and gui menu, yet of no use.
    also, my prime select GUI menu seems different. It dont have any side tabs. it consist of only 3 radio buttons to select the processor.

```
Do someone have solution for this?
```

edit:
after installing the util-440, the `nvidia-smi` is working and in that, it shows `gforce mx230 off` but  the gpu usage is never 0%. Also, `settings>about system` shows `intel` and `prime-select query` shows `nvidia`.
the output of `nvidia-smi` :

```
Tue Apr 21 17:21:44 2020       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 440.82       Driver Version: 440.82       CUDA Version: 10.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce MX230       Off  | 00000000:02:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   47C    P3    N/A /  N/A |    287MiB /  2002MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      1453      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                            28MiB |
|    0      2042      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                            83MiB |
|    0      2306      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                         128MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

can someone please tell me is my NVIDIA active? if not then how do i make it active?

Comment: How about Secure Boot? Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 added that. check now.

Comment: I don't see any trace of Nvidia driver installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by first completely uninstalling all the drivers.
Then reinstalling nvidia-440 driver since my GPU is MX230.
Also, along with it, i installed nvidia-utils-440 package
now nvidia-smi works perfectly.
Though there are instances when i switch on the system and the command dont respond or the GPU is listed but inactive so i simply shut down and start again and this fixes the issue. 
Hope this helps you too.
Also, i have installed nvidia-418 and nvidia-utils-418
now in additional drivers, 418 is unlisted even after installing, i don't know why? but this have worked for me.Hope it do for you too.

Answer (score -1):

First and foremost, try out all the available Nvidia drivers available to you in the Additional Drivers section of Software and Updates (`software-properties-gtk`). For instance, I have three different versions available. If you have not installed the driver on your own, then you are probably using the open-source Nouveau drivers. Nvidia recently released `v418.56` for MX 230. Install that and see whether it solves your issues.

If it still isn't detectable, try out the Nvidia-release of Pop!OS. Being based on Ubuntu, you will not have to modify your workflow in a significant way.